# Make my Django app into a rentable service for companies

Tags: django, saas, business-application

I have a webapp running with Django. I would like to make an Enterprise Edition of this website. In exchange for a yearly fee, I would like to allow companies to host the webapp on their own server and benefit from unique features

The problem is that I have no idea how to proceed. How can I execute this, without sending my whole code over to their computer and launching the django app there?

Is there something like generating an .exe that would run the django app without sending my code? How do companies usually proceed to make their tools available on another company's intranet?

Comment: You can't do it without sending your code over. That *is* how companies usually proceed for on-prem installations.

Comment: You could send an [obfuscated version of your code](https://reverseengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/1943/what-are-the-techniques-and-tools-to-obfuscate-python-programs/1974#1974).

Answer (score 1):

well I haven't heard something like that, but what you can do is using a license in your code, there are many types of licenses, from open source to trade secret license, read more about [it](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Software_license)